# Custom PHP code on WordPress blocks the entire page content

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a simple code for my WordPress site that redirects anyone who is not logged in to a page, it looks like this:

```
<?php 

global $current_user;

$currentuserid = $current_user->ID;

if( $currentuserid > 0 ){ 

} else {
    wp_redirect( 'https://site/?error=unauthorized' );
    }
    exit;
?>
```

the code works fine but the issue I'm facing is that when I add it to a WordPress site using a plugin like "insert code snippets", when the code runs, it blocks the entire page content and I don't want that to happen.

For example, when the user is logged in and this code is not supposed to do anything, it shows a white page. Any idea how this can be fixed or what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `exit()` is outside the closing brace of the else, so it's getting run every time. See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) for docs.

> Note: wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost always be followed by a call to exit;

You want:

```php
$currentuserid = $current_user->ID;
if ($currentuserid > 0) { 
} else {
    wp_redirect('https://site/?error=unauthorized');
    exit;
}
```

Or better, invert your if statement so that you don't have an empty condition, and use the null coalesce operator so that you don't have to use a temporary variable to hold the id:

```php
if ($current_user->ID ?? 0 <= 0) { 
    wp_redirect('https://site/?error=unauthorized');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: this worked! I appreciate you very much!